# How to draw a Tag on Image Bitmap?

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I need help to do the following task. My task is similar to [Pose](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pose&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wb3NlIl0.) (an Android application). In this application they done a amazing concept. Once you capture the image, then tap any part of the image it shows number of options to add tagline. Once you add the tag means the particular tag is added over the image. once you upload the image to server, now you can view in your profile, once you touch on the image, the tag parts are visible, then you again touch the image means the tagged icons are disappeared. How they do this think, if they are using any third party tool?.Here for your reference i added the market link of Pose application also having a video and Sample images and i also added some images kindly  notice it. Kindly share you valuable suggestion to completed this task.

[image: Captured Image]
[image: Tag option]
[image: Tag added image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FrameLayout` and try to position the tags over the image that way, however I would probably make a custom `View`, override the `onDraw` method and do custom drawing for all of this.

Comment: if i pass this image to server means i must all send the position's am i right?

Comment: Yes, you would probably have X and Y coordinates for all the tags on the image and send / pull them from the server.

Comment: @Joru: is there any example is there, regarding this

Comment: There's information on making a custom view here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html